# Spherical harmonics for two particle?

Tags: angular-momentum

For one particle angular momentum eigenket, we can represent it in position space, such as

$\langle\theta,\phi|l,m\rangle=Y_{lm}$

where $Y_{lm}$ means spherical harmonics.

But if we have we have two particle with angular momentum $\frac{1}{2}$(of course no angular momentum $\frac{1}{2}$ particle, but for simplicity) , the total angular momentum state $|10\rangle$ can be represented by sum of each angular momentum,

$|10\rangle$=$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle)+|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle$

At this stage, what is $\langle\theta,\phi|1,1\rangle$, when the added angular momentum represened in position space??

First I thought that it was

$\langle\theta,\phi|10\rangle$ $= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\langle\theta,\phi|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle)+\langle\theta,\phi|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle)\\=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(Y_{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}}(\theta,\phi)Y_{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}}(\theta,\phi)+Y_{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}}(\theta,\phi)Y_{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}}(\theta,\phi))$

$\langle\theta,\phi|10\rangle$ $= Y_{1,0}(\theta, \phi)$

thus

$ Y_{1,0}(\theta, \phi) = \langle\theta,\phi|10\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(Y_{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}}(\theta,\phi)Y_{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}}(\theta,\phi)+Y_{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}}(\theta,\phi)Y_{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}}(\theta,\phi))$

but if we think the bra operator, $\langle\theta,\phi|$ acts on total angular momentum state, it cannot acts on each particle's hilbert space, I think the right side of last equation cannot be hold.

so I thought that I have to find the corresponding operator of $\langle\theta,\phi|$,  which acts on total angular momentum hilbert space,  to each particle's space, but I'm not sure about this idea.

Is this right? if then, what is that operator?

Comment: Note that $\theta,\phi$ are coordinates of one particle, while you have two. What state would then $\langle\theta,\phi|$ denote?

Comment: The standard procedure to systematically build multi-particle angular momentum states is through a procedure featuring Clebsch-Gordan coefficients. It is discussed in advanced quantum mechanics books and physically oriented books on group theory.